# How to prevent a remote WireGuard server establishing new connections to on-premises computers?

Tags: vpn, firewall, wireguard, mikrotik

[In RouterOS 7.15 Wireguard](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/WireGuard) setup there is an option to mark peer as **RESPONDER ONLY** (NOT INITIATOR). I wish I could mark my VPN provider's server exactly this way, but I can't. But maybe there is a way to mark my local peer as **INITIATOR ONLY**, NOT RESPONDER for connections initiated by other peers.

If there is a solution can you suggest one?

Goals:

- I want to prevent my VPN provider's server from initiating any
  connections to my local computers (so I don't need to filter them with my firewall).
- I want only my local WireGuard setup to be able to ask my VPN provider for establishing tunnel, never the other way around.
- I want to allow all my local traffic to go through a WireGuard
  tunnel, so I set my `allowed IPs` to `0.0.0.0/0`.

Obstacles:

- I can't set my provider site allowed IPs to none, so none of its new connection goes through tunnel to me. Can I?
- AFAIK any WireGuard endpoint can act as both a server and a client, so I can't prevent them from switching roles. Can I?

PS. Wireguard client is configured on Mikrotik.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.